# How to validate phone number in Twilio using Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.1, twilio

I am using [Twilio Api](https://www.twilio.com/) to send sms to users, it gives fatal error if user's phone number is invalid. I want to validate the phone number before sending messages.

Currently I am using the following method to validate it:

```
public function get_web_page($url) {
            $options = array(
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,   // return web page
                CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,  // don't return headers
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,   // follow redirects
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,     // stop after 10 redirects
                CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",     // handle compressed
                CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "test", // name of client
                CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,   // set referrer on redirect
                CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,    // time-out on connect
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,    // time-out on response
            ); 

            $session = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt_array($session, $options);
            $content  = curl_exec($session);

            curl_close($session);

            return $content;
        }

$response = $this->get_web_page("https://credentials:removed@lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/3234433584");
        $resArr = array();
        $resArr = json_decode($response)
```

and it works fine.

But I want to validate it using Twilio's inbuilt functionality. I have searched a lot on internet, but nothing helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://twilio-php.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/rest/callerids.html#validate-a-phone-number) is a wonderful resource for questions like that.

The [Twilio SDK](https://packagist.org/packages/twilio/sdk) has a [method](https://twilio-php.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/rest/callerids.html#validate-a-phone-number) for that specific feature:

I'll copy and paste directly from the documentation:

```
<?php
$client = new Services_Twilio('AC123', '123');
$response = $client->account->outgoing_caller_ids->create('+15554441234');
print $response->validation_code;
```

You can see examples of responses by trying out their online lookup functionality: https://www.twilio.com/lookup

Comment: hi thanks for answering, i have tried this, it gives following error instead of any response "Services_Twilio_RestException in Twilio.php line 297: The phone number you are attempting to call, +15554441234, is not valid."

Comment: @Insomania, that's not wrong. You need to catch the `Services_Twilio_RestException` when a number isn't valid. Look up the PHP manual on [Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: yo! man, you are great, i have learned a new thing today, thanks so much it worked :)